# Problems with accessing a Model in the Admin website

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I have created Profile model, which works fine in the admin website in Django, obviously, I try creating a very complex model but I keep getting error, anyway decided to streamline the process and I created a very simple model.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
#from django_countries.fields import CountryField
#from phone_field import PhoneField

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True,null=True)
    role = models.TextField(blank=True)
    location = models.TextField(blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Profile for user {self.user.username}'

class Client(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.firstname}'
```

I ran  `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` and the code works fine, I have also ensured that all previous migrations are deleted, so I successfully created a 0001_initial.py file in migrations.

I decided to include my new model in the admin.py file so I can interact with the model from Django's user interface

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile, Client

@admin.register(Profile)
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'photo','role']

@admin.register(Client)
class Client(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['firstname']
    #list_display = ['firstname', 'lastname','position','country','email','phone']
```

And this is where the problem starts, I can successfully see that the **Clients** model is create din the admin section, but when I click the model - I'm getting this error  `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: account_client`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 616, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 232, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1697, in changelist_view
    cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 736, in get_changelist_instance
    return ChangeList(
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.get_results(request)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py", line 235, in get_results
    result_count = paginator.count
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 97, in count
    return c()
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 412, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 519, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 504, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\fcolina\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: account_client
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue are welcome

Comment: Have you tried to register your models with `admin.site.register(Client)`? And it seems that you are defining a Client twice, you would need to set it to `ClientAdmin` and not `Client`. You might also want to check via `python manage.py shell` to see if your tables really do exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace says it all and it seems like your app can't find the table `account_client`. Something must've gone wrong when you did your migration. if it's possible, start with a fresh DB or at least drop all tables. Then remove all your migration files and redo the `makemigrations` command. After that, you're good to go! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

run normal migrations

```
python manage.py makemigrations <your-app-name>
python manage.py migrate <your-app-name>
```

If that did not work, try to add this to each model:

```
class Meta:
        app_label = '<your-app-name>'
```

run normal migrations

```
python manage.py makemigrations <your-app-name>
python manage.py migrate <your-app-name>
```

If still  then:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <your-app-name>
python manage.py migrate <your-app-name> --fake
```

If all options did not work then you have two options:

- **option 1**

1. check manually if table exist in the database
2. if table does not exist manually create the table in the db.

- **option 2**

1. if its debugging database and there is no important information delete it, delete migrations and run migrations again.